# simple_form validation message for a field not in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, model, simple-form

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
   attr_accessor :date
   validates_presence_of :name, :principalAmount,:interestRate,:accountType,:duration,:date
end
```

Except `date` all are there in my `customers` table. I am using `simple_form` for getting those values. But problem is that there is no validation happening for `:date`.For others it displays message if the field is empty. How do I display  `presence_of` validation message in simple_form for `:date`. I am using bootstrap datepicker.

```
  <%= simple_form_for @customer do |f| %>
          <%= f.input :name,:autocomplete => :off %>
          <%= f.input :principalAmount,:autocomplete => :off %>
          <%= f.input :interestRate %>
          <%= f.input :accountType %>
          <%= f.input :duration,:autocomplete => :off %>
          <%= f.text_field :date, "data-provide" => 'datepicker',"data-date-format"=>"dd-mm-yyyy" %>
          <%= f.button :submit %>
        <% end %>
```

Edit: When I change `f.text_field` to `f.input` it shows the validation message. But it is no more a date picker.

Comment: Why isn't date at the database? This way it won't be saved..

Comment: Actually I have to save that in another database not in the customers table. That I am doing separate. Just need the validation here.

Comment: If it is in another table, isn't it an association?

Comment: Consider that as a database to dump some testing values. So no association with that.

Comment: I think above is not working because of f.text_field, others are f.input. How do I make it in input format?

Comment: Yeah.. it may make sense, maybe f.text_field will fill it with something even though you didn't put anything. You can try to use f.date_select, which is a helper for dates..

Comment: while creation , f.date_select gives error - undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass

Comment: this most probably have something to do with the parameters passed by rails date helpers and strong_parameters.  check the parameters you receive from the browser against the parameters you permit.